# ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis when using FK

Tags: oracle, foreign-keys

```
SQL>
SQL> CREATE TABLE Recipe
(Quantity_used DECIMAL (2,1)
FOREIGN KEY "ICECREAM_ID"
REFERENCES icecreamGT(Icecream_id),
FOREIGN KEY (ingredient_id) REFERENCES ingredient (Ingredient_name),
);
  2    3    4    5    6  FOREIGN KEY "ICECREAM_ID"
*
ERROR at line 3:
ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis
```

[image: picture of code and structure]

**UPDATED**: new code with adjusted commas and parenthesis

```
CREATE TABLE Recipe 
(
Quantity_used DECIMAL (2,1),
FOREIGN KEY (ID_icecream)
REFERENCES icecreamGT(Icecream_id)
FOREIGN KEY (ID_ingredient)
REFERENCES ingredient(Ingredient_name)
);
```

[image: new code]

Comment: check your commas and parenthesis...

Comment: i took out the commas after

Comment: SQL> CREATE TABLE Recipe
(
Quantity_used DECIMAL (2,1),
FOREIGN KEY (ID_icecream)
REFERENCES icecreamGT(Icecream_id)
FOREIGN KEY (ID_ingredient)
REFERENCES ingredient(Ingredient_name)
);
  2    3    4    5    6    7    8  FOREIGN KEY (ID_ingredient)
*
ERROR at line 6:
ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis

now it moved the error to line 6

Comment: Please do not add code as comments as they are very hard to read there.  Instead, [edit] the question and add it there.

Comment: You updated the commas but what about the parenthesis? perhaps it's best to check the documentation on how to create a new table in Oracle https://www.oracletutorial.com/oracle-basics/oracle-create-table/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your statement does not have:

- An `icecream_id` column in the `recipe` table;
- An `ingredient_id` column in the `recipe` table;
- Commas in the correct places;
- `()` Brackets around the `"ICECREAM_ID"` identifier in the column list of the foreign key.

I.e.:

```sql
CREATE TABLE Recipe(
  Quantity_used   DECIMAL (2,1),
  icecream_id     NUMBER,
  ingredient_id   NUMBER,
  FOREIGN KEY (ICECREAM_ID) REFERENCES icecreamGT(Icecream_id),
  FOREIGN KEY (ingredient_id) REFERENCES ingredient (Ingredient_name)
);
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=bf1ef32f9735dbfc22ea15c6bf248c85)*